# How to track share view open / close swift in QLPreviewController

Tags: ios, swift, qlpreviewcontroller

Is there a way to track if the "share" view in QLPreviewController is presented and closed?

Comment: What is your actual goal? What are you trying to accomplish? Why would you need to "spy" on your user?

Comment: I don't want to spy, I have set my UINavigationBar appearance globally. However, when the sheet presents system viewControllers it keeps my apps tint color which is white so they are not visible. I want to know when the button is tapped so I can change on view/dismiss of that screen..

Comment: Still not clear what is your issue  and/or what you are asking. Can't you illustrate your issue?

Answer (score 0):

I think the question here is if the action sheet presented by the share bar button at the top of the `QLPreviewController` is providing any delegate functionality like `willPresent` or `didDismiss` to change the `UINavigationBar` appearance each time the action sheet is presented/pushed or dismissed/popped. Imho `QLPreviewController` does not come with that feature.

I guess you could have a look at `UIActivityViewController` which offers delegate functionality in form of completion handling closures. But for that to work you need to implement your own sharing feature capturing the button action there, switching the colours and switching them back inside the completion handler.